# Refactoring similar routes in Express, extracting callbacks to separate modules

Tags: node.js, express, refactoring

I have separated my routes into different modules. However, there still is a fair amount of duplication. Are there some good practices and conventions that are taking shape around how to extract code out of routes?

I have numerous routes that effectively look like this (Express 4.x):

```
router.get('/:something', function(req, res, next) {
  manipulate(something);
  Model.findOne( ..., function (err, model) {
    doSomethingInterestingWith(model, function(err, model) {
      res.render('template', { something: model} );
    });
  });
});

router.post('/:something', function(req, res, next) {
  manipulate(something);
  Model.new( {...}).save( function(err, model) {
    res.redirect('/:something');
  });
});
```

This is in a file called, for example, `routes/something.js`.

I'm fiddling with ways to extract the guts of each route into a function that can be extracted to a separate file. I've tried to simplify the example as much as possible, to keep this readable, but in reality, there is a fair amount of code before the call to render. The nested callbacks make my extracted functions pretty ugly. I've thought about using Q and promises, but I'm fearful of using a sledgehammer to swat a fly.

Comment: The fly had it coming. You can always use function generators to fill in boilerplate. You can also use a module-specific middleware to encapsulate repeated logic. (And combine the two if it's used throughout your app; middleware can also be generated by a function.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood you question fully based on your first part of question you can achieve this in two ways.

### Little Cleaner way

Move the common logic to router.param

router.param will get executed for any request methods once in this case "GET" and "POST"
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.param

```
router.param('name', function(req, res, next) {
    manipulate(something);
    //set return value if needed
    //req.something = manipulate(something);
    next();
});

router.get('/:something', function(req, res) {
  //access returned value if needed
  //var modifiedSomething = req.params.something;
  Model.findOne( ..., function (err, model) {
    doSomethingInterestingWith(model, function(err, model) {
      res.render('template', { something: model} );
    });
  });
});

router.post('/:something', function(req, res) {
  //access returned value if needed
  //var modifiedSomething = req.params.something;
  Model.new( {...}).save( function(err, model) {
    res.redirect('/:something');
  });
});
```

### More Cleaner way

Make use of .all and chain the callbacks.

"/:something" request .all() callback will always run once and then based on the request method "GET" or "POST" corresponding callbacks will get executed.

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.route

```
router.route('/:something')
.all(function (request, response, next) {
    manipulate(something);
    next();
})
.get(function(req, res) {
  Model.findOne( ..., function (err, model) {
    doSomethingInterestingWith(model, function(err, model) {
      res.render('template', { something: model} );
    });
  });
})
.post(function(req, res) {
  Model.new( {...}).save( function(err, model) {
    res.redirect('/:something');
  });
});
```